# setuid(0) with CAP_SETUID

Tags: linux, privileges, linux-capabilities

I am trying to change my uid to 0 as non-root with the `CAP_SETUID` capability. I have the following program:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/capability.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("cap setuid in bset: %d\n", prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, CAP_SETUID, 0, 0, 0));
    printf("%s\n", cap_to_text(cap_get_file(argv[0]), NULL));
    printf("%s\n", cap_to_text(cap_get_proc(), NULL));
    printf("uid: %d\n", (int) getuid());
    setresuid(0, 0, 0);
    printf("uid: %d\n", (int) getuid());
    return 0;
}
```

I assign the setuid capability as follows:

```
sudo /sbin/setcap cap_setuid=ep ./capsetuid
```

And I get the following output

```
cap setuid in bset: 1
= cap_setuid+ep
=
uid: 1000
uid: 1000
```

I would expect the second printf() to also show the `CAP_SETUID` capability. Somehow my process does not get the setuid file capability. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This might help: http://blog.famzah.net/tag/cap_setuid/

Comment: This also seems to have relevant information - especially near the end: http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities

Comment: It looks like the process must have the CAP_SETUID privilege (as well as, or instead of, the file).

Comment: @Jonathan: I just updated the question, you may have been looking at the old question. I found the problem to be that the process does not get the file capabilities, see updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found out that file capabilities need to be enabled on the kernel commandline with file_caps=1.

Answer (score 2):

`setuid()` sets the *effective* user-id of the process, but `getuid()` gets the *real* user-id.

Change the `getuid()` to `geteuid()` and it should work.

Comment: If `setuid()` sets the effective UID, what does the `seteuid()` function do?  Part of the answer is "the same"; the difference is that `setuid()` does set the real and effective and saved UID values to the given UID if the process has 'appropriate privileges'.  Then the subsidiary question is "does possessing the CAP_SETUID privilege confer the appropriate privileges"?

Comment: euid doesn change neither. The man page says: "If the effective UID of the caller is root, the real UID and saved set-user-ID are also set." I am not root, though, I am priviliged. So I am not sure what happens in my case. I found the problem is in my process not getting the cap_setuid capability. I've updated the question

Comment: @Fabian: Does your kernel have file capabilities enabled (`CONFIG_SECURITY_FILE_CAPABILITIES=y`)? What does ` prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, CAP_SETUID, 0, 0, 0)` return?

Comment: My kernel does have file capabilities. prctl() returns 1. So from I understand from the manpage, this means that my process does not get cap_setuid because it is blocked by the bounding capability set. Right? How do I change the bounding cap set?

Comment: the problem was that file capabilities must be enabled on the kernel command line.

Answer (score 0):

Filesysem with mount option `nosuid` set could be another reason. `tmpfs` for example sets `nosuid` and thus causes setcap does not take effect at all.